# Show title and snippet upon marker creation

Tags: android, google-maps

I wish to add a marker to a googleMap with an editable title and snippet. The marker should appear when the user does a long click on the map and then the marker should appear showing a title of something like "click to edit".

The code is all up and running except that I can not figure out how to get the title to appear the moment the marker is created. I can only make it appear with a subsequent click on the marker. I can not see anything within MarkerOptions that allows me to do this. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option your looking for is not in `MarkerOptions` it is a function of the `Marker` itself. [Here's a link to the related docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#showInfoWindow%28%29)

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

To call this method you need to have the marker, or a reference to it. If you're doing this on creation it should be easy. Otherwise just store your makers in some collection - like a `HashMap` so they are easy to find - and you can display the info window whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to display your marker's title and snippet in your own custom way - you may set it in the `onMapReadyCallback`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_info, null);

            TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.marker_title);
            textViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

            TextView textViewSnippet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.marker_snippet);
            textViewSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

            return view;
        }
    });
```

And here is my layout file for the same.
`marker_info.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```